# Propagating changes across un-boxed variables

Tags: c#

I just did a little experiment to see if altering an un-boxed variable would propagate changes made to the original source and got two completely different results depending on the types that I used. I am mainly interested in figuring this out for WPF data binding applications in which I bind to `object`s, cast, change, and hope that the original's update their UIs.

My results were as follows.

1. Simple types seem to lose their reference to the original source after un-boxing.
2. Custom types seem to keep their reference.

It seems that I don't have anything to worry about in my scenario of hoping that my WPF UI updates itself after making changes to unboxed bound data contexts; however, not knowing WHY this happens only with complex objects worries me a bit. I do not want my UI to fail on rare or odd occasions I do not know about. Can anyone explain what the heck is mechanically going on back there?

```
class Program
{
    //simple types
    private static object sbox1;
    private static object sbox2;

    private static int svalue1 = 10;
    private static int svalue2 = 15;

    //custom types
    private static MyType cvalue1;
    private static MyType cvalue2;

    private static object cbox1;
    private static object cbox2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Box up the values
        sbox1 = svalue1;
        sbox2 = svalue2;

        //unbox the values to local var
        var sunboxed1 = (int)sbox1;
        var sunboxed2 = (int)sbox2;

        //change the values in the new unboxed vars
        sunboxed1 = -10;
        sunboxed2 = -15;

        //check unboxed values and check original value variables
        Console.WriteLine("unboxed1 = " + sunboxed1);
        Console.WriteLine("unboxed2 = " + sunboxed2);
        Console.WriteLine("value1 = " + svalue1);
        Console.WriteLine("value2 = " + svalue2);

        //Now try hand at custom types
        cvalue1 = new MyType() { Example = "I am cvalue1's original string." };
        cvalue2 = new MyType() { Example = "I am cvalue2's original string." };

        //now box them up.
        cbox1 = cvalue1;
        cbox2 = cvalue2;

        //now unbox and change the strings
        var cunboxed1 = cbox1 as MyType;
        var cunboxed2 = cbox2 as MyType;

        //change the original strings to see if they propogate to original objects
        cunboxed1.Example = "I am cunboxed1's altered string.";
        cunboxed2.Example = "I am cunboxed2's altered string.";

        //print unboxed and originals values to compare
        Console.WriteLine("cunboxed1.Example = " + cunboxed1.Example);
        Console.WriteLine("cunboxed2.Example = " + cunboxed2.Example);
        Console.WriteLine("cvalue1.Example = " + cvalue1.Example);
        Console.WriteLine("cvalue2.Example = " + cvalue2.Example);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
}
```

Results from the tester app:

```
unboxed1 = -10  
unboxed2 = -15  
value1 = 10  
value2 = 15  
cunboxed1.Example = I am cunboxed1's altered string.  
cunboxed2.Example = I am cunboxed2's altered string.  
cvalue1.Example = I am cunboxed1's altered string.  
cvalue2.Example = I am cunboxed2's altered string.
```

Comment: Can you also include in your question the output of your program ?

Comment: This is the question not about boxing / unboxing as you call it, but rather about value and reference types.

Comment: search in google: "value types vs reference types" and you will find your answer

Comment: Ahhh okay.. numeric = value.

Comment: What's weird is how value types inside classes suddenly seem to work like reference types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is caused by the different handling of value and reference types. In the first example, you are boxing an `int`. This is wrapped in `Int32`, a value type, and assigned to your `object` variable. In your unboxing step, the original `Int32` object is copied, because it is a value type, and its value is assigned to your `int` variable `sunboxed1`. `sbox1` and `sunboxed1` hold different values and exist at different memory locations, so no change made to one will affect the other.

In your second example, you are assigning a class to an `object` variable. This isn't boxing it; you're simply upcasting a reference to your object. When you subsequently downcast it back to `MyType` with the `as` keyword, you get a reference to the original object. So, `cvalue1` and `cunboxed1` hold a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

As dotnetom stated this is more about value vs reference types.

According to MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx
*A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation. Value types include the following:
All numeric data types....*

However, for classes:
*A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data. Reference types include the following: Class types, such as Form.....*

With the last line being the most interesting.
*A class is a reference type. For this reason, reference types such as Object and String are supported by .NET Framework classes. Note that every array is a reference type, **even if its members are value types**.*

This is why the custom types above changed the original values above after un-boxing. strings themselves are reference types so it it might seem that the reason changes were propogated was due to me using a string as an example and not a numeric type; however, changing the `Example` property to an int will still change the original source as well and yield the same results.